# C User input validation - only one character which converts to int needed

Tags: c, char, int, validation, getchar

I have problem taking user input in C. I want to take the first number only. I filter the user input from characters but when I enter 2 digits(wrong user input) the program starts to behave strange

it displays:

```
Turn 2 : What number? 21
Turn 2 : What number?  1 6 2 4 2
```

---

```
//User input validation
int GetColorGuess(int counter)
{
    int color=1;
    int inputChar=' ';
    do{
        printf("Turn %d : What number? ",counter);
        inputChar=getchar();
        getchar();
    }
    while(inputChar<((int)'1') || inputChar>selectedColorSize+'0');

    color = digit_to_int(inputChar);

    return color;
}
//convert char which represents digit to int
int digit_to_int(char d)
{
 char str[2];
 str[0] = d;
 str[1] = '\0';
 return (int) strtol(str, NULL, 10);
}
```

Can anyone help me what is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

When entering "21" your first `getchar()` reads the '2', the next `getchar()`, which probably should eat the newline, reads the '1'. when then entering "3" your first `getchar()` reads the newline and your second `getchar()` reads the '3'. Change your code to use `sscanf` instead.